# Pyqt5: How to use SH_ToolTip_WakeUpDelay?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

I've read that I can use `QStyle.SH_ToolTip_WakeUpDelay` to create a delay before the tool tip is shown, but I didn't figured out how exactly. I already read this question: [How do I use QStyle::SH_ToolTip_WakeUpDelay to set tooltip wake-up time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719739/how-do-i-use-qstylesh-tooltip-wakeupdelay-to-set-tooltip-wake-up-time)
I'm not familiar with C++, but I tried to recreate it. I just made a class and overwrited the method `styleHint`, but it doesn't work.

My code:

```
class ProxyStyle(QProxyStyle):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def styleHint(self, hint: QStyle.StyleHint, option: Optional['QStyleOption'] = ..., widget: Optional[QWidget] = ..., returnData: Optional['QStyleHintReturn'] = ...) -> int:
        if hint == QStyle.SH_ToolTip_WakeUpDelay:
            return 1000   # I just assumed it's in milliseconds, so I did 1000 to have a delay of 1s.
 
        return QProxyStyle.styleHint(hint, option, widget, returnData)
```

As the guy answered in the above mentioned question, I added an instance of the class to my application. I don't know exactly if I understood it correctly, but I just did that:

```
proxyStyle = QProxyStyle()
app = QApplication([proxyStyle])
app.exec()
```

###### Edit

I did it like that now, but it also doesn't work (I expect a 1s delay):

```
proxyStyle = QProxyStyle()
app = QApplication([])
app.setStyle(proxyStyle)
```

Comment: You can set the style with [QApplication::setStyle()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#setStyle)

Comment: I did that but it doesn't work. I edited the question

Comment: Add a debug output to see if styleHint and your case statement is called at all.

Comment: Create the style *after* the application. Also provide a [mre] and the output of `print(app.style.objectName())` before setting the proxy style.

Comment: Please check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57007003/qproxystyle-with-qstylesheet

Comment: Your `styleHint` implementation is broken because `self` isn't passed in the base-class call. Use `return super().styleHint(hint, option, widget, returnData)` instead. Also, insert the line `print('style-hint:', hint)` as the first line of the method to check that it's being called with the relevant hint.